# Stop animation when mouse is over the box & animate it back when mouse is out, does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

I have a list of images that I display in an html page side by side grouped in a div. when there are many images that force the div to be expanded, the div will scroll automatically from left to right vice versa.

When the user puts the cursor on that div, the animation should stop, and when the cursor goes out, the animation should start again. But it doesn't work, sometimes it stops, sometimes not.

**HTML** rendered by django

```
<div class="row" style="position: relative;">
    <div id='mainDiv' class="col-sm-12" style="">
         <h1">Title</h1><hr>
         <div style="overflow:hidden;white-space: nowrap;">

             {% for img in all_images %}
                 <div class="" style="height:200px;display:inline-block"> 
                 <img height="100" title="" src="{{img.scr}}"> 
                 </div>      
             {% endfor %}

         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function animatethis(targetElement, speed) {
            var scrollWidth = $(targetElement).get(0).scrollWidth;
            var clientWidth = $(targetElement).get(0).clientWidth;
            $(targetElement).animate({ scrollLeft: scrollWidth - clientWidth },
            {
                duration: speed,
                complete: function () {
                    targetElement.animate({ scrollLeft: 0 },
                    {
                        duration: speed,
                        complete: function () {
                            animatethis(targetElement, speed);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        };
        var sec = 20000;
        animatethis($('#mainDiv'), sec);

        $("#mainDiv").hover(function(){
            $(this).stop(true)
        });
        $("#mainDiv").mouseout(function(){
            animatethis($(this), sec);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
--- <div id="mainDiv" class="col-sm-12" style="">
+++ <div class="col-sm-12" style="">
---   <div style="overflow:hidden;white-space: nowrap;">
+++   <div id="mainDiv" style="overflow:hidden;white-space: nowrap;">
```

You have the mainDiv id tag in the container component. That's not the div you're targeting to animated.

Here's a working one: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KxgdWO